# :not() fails to work on $('body') with newer jQuery

Tags: jquery

i've a page that used to use a class to disable triggers until the page was substantially loaded. example clip:

---

```
$('body').addClass('disable');

// mark unsaved changes
$('body:not(.disable)').on('change', '.CE', function(ev) {
    // mark_if_changed() is at the bottom of this file
    mark_if_changed($(this));
});
```

*[...load most of dynamic content without firing triggers...]*

```
$('body').removeClass('disable');
```

---

the point of the triggers is to update the database when fields with the CE class are modified.  using the above, it doesn't work.

if i delete ":not(.disable)", changes are updated -- but a lot of unecessary callbacks are invoked during the initial page load.

with jQuery 1.7, it worked, using .live().  with 1.9, it's not working, using .on().  i can remove the :not() and test to see if 'disable' is a member of the class attribute but that feels like duct taping a problem rather than fixing it.

https://dragonstone-mill.com/tabbed.html is the page i'm using it with.

all of the above is invoked in an orderly fashion subsequent to $(document).ready(), see ~ln:103 in tabbed.html which loads the functions and bindings.

is there a better/more correct way of doing this?

Comment: Instead of adding the class 'disable' within the javascript - why not add it in the plain HTML? (side note, not a solution to the problem)

Comment: because it is enabled and disabled as things happen on the page

Comment: You're wanting everything on the page to be unusable while the page loads?

Comment: i don't want any .on('change') bindings to fire.  the html is drawn and has hundreds of inputs.  the input fields are filled with existing values.  the change event fires if you modify input fields.  there's zero purpose in reacting to any of those changes during initial page load as there's no real change in the input data, it's just the initial populating of data.  once the page is finished loading, change reaction is enabled.  when the user changes an input field, now it's appropriate to react to that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler setup is not quite right.

Instead of this:

```
$('body:not(.disable)').on('change', '.CE', function(ev) {
```

Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'body:not(.disable) .CE', function(ev) {
```

Right now, you are checking if the body is disabled *when you attach the event handler*. You want to attach the event handler no matter what, but only *run* it if your selector matches. Try that and see if it works as expected.

Comment: awesome.  i had an inkling it was something like that :)  i assume the semantic differences between .live() and .on() are the reason why it worked in older jQuery